# Why can't I send an extrinsic from py-substrate-interface?

Tags: python, blockchain, substrate, polkadot

Hello guys I am working on submitting an extrinsic via the [py-substrate-interface](https://github.com/polkascan/py-substrate-interface), but for some reason I keep getting an error while following the sample mentioned [here](https://github.com/polkascan/py-substrate-interface#create-and-send-signed-extrinsics).
My code is as follows:

```
    def send_funds(self, destination, amount):
        self.log.info("Sending {} DOT to {} ...".format(amount, destination.strip()))
        substrate = self.create_substrate_instance(self.node_ws_port[0])

        keypair = Keypair.create_from_mnemonic('level payment mom grape proof display cause engage erupt rain hair arm')
        print(keypair)

        call = substrate.compose_call(
            call_module='Balances',
            call_function='transfer',
            call_params={
                'dest': destination,
                'value': ceil(amount * DOT)
            }
        )

        try:
            extrinsic = substrate.create_signed_extrinsic(call=call, keypair=keypair)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

        try:
            receipt = substrate.submit_extrinsic(extrinsic, wait_for_inclusion=True)
            self.log.info("Extrinsic '{}' sent and included in block '{}'".format(receipt.extrinsic_hash, receipt.block_hash))
            self.log.info("{} DOT sent to address: {}".format(amount, destination))
        except SubstrateRequestException as e:
            self.log.error("Failed to send: {}".format(e))
```

I put a try and except block here:

```
        try:
            extrinsic = substrate.create_signed_extrinsic(call=call, keypair=keypair)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

and I get the following error while running this code block:

```
No more bytes available (offset: 80 / length: 72)
```

How can I resolve this problem.

Comment: ICYMI the Polkascan Technical channel  is a good place to ask  : https://matrix.to/#/#polkascan:matrix.org

Comment: Just solved my problem :) ty anyways

Comment: great! Would you mind adding the tag `python-substrate` to this question? so others can find it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of the time a `RemainingScaleBytesNotEmptyException` is raised, it is type registry related. In a Substrate runtime (like Kusama, Polkadot, etc) specific types are defined, which are not (yet) exposed in the metadata, so libraries have to include a decomposition to primitives of those types.

Some pointers for troubleshooting:

- The wrong type registry is being used. Most of the time py-substrate-interface can auto-discover which chain its talking to, so only the `url` have to be specified (https://github.com/polkascan/py-substrate-interface#autodiscover-mode). But with custom runtimes or development properties like `type_registry_preset` and `ss58_format` need to be set manually
- Because of a recent runtime upgrade the local type registry is out-dated and needs to be updated. This can be achieved by updating the `py-scale-codec` package, run the `substrate.reload_type_registry()` function or always use the remote type registries with the `use_remote_preset` kwarg (See https://github.com/polkascan/py-substrate-interface#keeping-type-registry-presets-up-to-date)
- When developing a custom runtime, introduced types can be added in a custom JSON file in the format like https://github.com/polkascan/py-scale-codec/blob/master/scalecodec/type_registry/rococo.json and provided during init (See https://github.com/polkascan/py-substrate-interface#substrate-node-template)

Answer (score 1):

OK after digging out a bit more found out that the issue was related to the encoding in parity-scale codec and you need to adjust the network configuration according to your runtime.
So I changed from:

```
    def create_substrate_instance(self, wsport):
        return SubstrateInterface(
                    url=self.rpc_url + wsport,
                    ss58_format=42,
                    type_registry_preset='kusama',
                )
```

to:

```
    def create_substrate_instance(self, wsport):
        return SubstrateInterface(
                    url=self.rpc_url + wsport,
                    ss58_format=42,
                    type_registry_preset='substrate-node-template',
                )
```

and it worked.